# Is it a good practice to use the "this" pointer in class methods?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm wondering if it's a good practice to use it or simply leave it as the name itself. I know sometimes it's better to use it to understand what you're calling, but if it's completely isolated and can be omitted, is it a good practice to still make use of it?

Is it, in any way, slower than not using it?

Comment: I don't know whether there is an objective answer to this question. It seems to be a matter of personal taste and/or team coding guideline.

Comment: It comes down to personnel preference and consistency. There isn't a definitive correct answer to this question. It has no impact on performance.

Comment: More typing can lead to more injected typos (defects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slower no, but it helps if there is a variable in scope which is the same as the closing members, you can use this to disambiguate between the two. You can also assign to this which functionality can also be overridden.